# Getting Started with Events - Consume and Dispatch

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am working on a Javascript file that will catch and consume a User's keystroke, when a specific one is pressed. Instead, that keystroke should dispatch a sequence of keystrokes.

So far, I have been able to successfully catch and consume the user's keystroke. However, I have not yet been able to dispatch the corresponding sequence.

The goal: When a user pressed [<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>], it should instead execute [<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>] [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>] [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>] (no recursion)

### The broken code:

```
function replaceKeyEvent(evtobj) {

if(evtobj.keyCode == 73 && evtobj.ctrlKey){
 window.alert("101");   
 }
if (evtobj.keyCode == 77 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {

  evtobj.preventDefault();
   window.alert("test");
/*
 var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
 evt.initKeyboardEvent();
 evt.ctrlKey = true;
 */
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
    bubbles : true,
    cancelable : true,
    char : "I",
    key : "i",
    shiftKey : false,
    ctrlKey : true,
    keyCode : 73

 });
 document.dispatchEvent(e);
 window.alert(e);

}
}

document.onkeydown = replaceKeyEvent;
```

so far I am just trying to catch the [<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>] and send the first keyboardevent (which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>), and as a test, when the script sees the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> it should alert 101 (intro joke yes I know).

Please let me know if anyone can assist. I am very new to dispatching events in general, let alone Javascript

Edit: also any  notes on cross functionality between environments (browser, os, etc.,) please point me in the right direction
edit2: updated code, still not working, stopping for the night

Comment: Events dispatched through javascript WILL NOT trigger key combinations. For example, if you dispatch Ctrl+v it will not paste. If that's what you're trying to do...it will not work. The only thing that it will do is trigger any javascript event handlers that are registered to listen for keystrokes

Comment: @markasoftware can you recommend a way to do this? I need something than can map the keystrokes for Mac and Windows. I was able to do it on windows using auto hot key , but that is not mac compatible and rollout of the script would be unfeasible with using a similar application on mac

Comment: you can't trigger key combinations from javascript, it's a security issue. For example, what if a malicious hacker wrote a script that triggered CTRL+v (paste), and then saved the result to the server. What if the user happened to have their credit card number or an important password in the clipboard? There are also a lot of other key combinations apart from paste that could be a security problem. So, there's not really any way to do key combinations like that from an automated script